# How to deal with unclassified variable in Matlab parfor loop?

Tags: matlab

I have following code and I want to make it parallel. But unfortunately when I use parfor loop I get following error. Here is the code:

```
    parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list) % over l1

        for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)

            params.lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
            params.lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);


            [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = Learn_weights(dictionary(train_set,:), y(train_set,:), params); 

end
end
```

and here is the error:

```
Error: The variable params in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

and here is how the *params* looks like
params =

```
lambda1_list: [1 1.5000 2 2.5000 3 3.5000 4 4.5000 5 5.5000 6 6.5000 7 7.5000 8 8.5000 9 9.5000 10]
lambda2_list: [1 1.5000 2 2.5000 3 3.5000 4 4.5000 5 5.5000 6 6.5000 7 7.5000 8 8.5000 9 9.5000 10]
    features: [50x2 double]
        mcut: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
learnWeights: 0
   beta_init: [50x10 double]
     lambda1: 10
     lambda2: 10
     stopVal: 1.0000e-05
```

I was wondering can someone help me with this? I need to have **params** in program and cuz it's thousands lines of codes and it used in different places.
I'm looking for trick to overcome to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are *modifying* `params` (the same exact data) within each iteration of the `parfor` loop. If you have two parallel jobs going, theoretically they would both be trying to change the *same* `params` structure which obviously is going to cause issues.

Your options are to create an *array* of `params` before the loop and then use each of the elements in the array.

```
%// Duplicate params once for each time through the parfor loop
params_array = repmat(params, size(lambda1_list));

parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list)
    for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)
        params_array(l1).lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
        params_array(l1).lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);

        [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = Learn_weights(dictionary(train_set,:), y(train_set,:), params_array(l1)); 
    end
end
```

The other option is to create a copy of `params` prior to modifying it.

```
parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list)

    %// Make a copy of the params that is local to this loop iteration
    this_param = params;

    for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)
        %// Modify this copy
        this_param.lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
        this_param.lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);

        %// Pass this modified copy to Learn_weights
        [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = Learn_weights(dictionary(train_set,:), y(train_set,:), this_param); 
    end
end
```